# floating list element with unwanted space

Tags: css, css-float, html-lists

I have a unordered list of thumbnails that work on every other page except one. On this one particular page, there is a large amount of whitespace on the third row. See below:

[image: spacing error]

I don't get why it is doing this, it happens even if you take away padding and margin. The page that this is doing this on is http://bransonweekend.net/cabins/trailsend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using:

```
.picture-board .pinned-photo img {
max-height: 160px;
}
```

and in that row the first image form factor makes it go the max-height but the other two are too wide so the height is less than the max 160px.

try adding this:

```
.thumbnails>li{
min-height:172px;
}
```

this will make sure they are the same height even if they are too wide

Comment: Nice catch.  I'm removing my answer suggesting `.picture-board .pinned-photo { display: inline-table; }` as this is much better.

Comment: Wow, never would have noticed that! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this library:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

It's useful in cases like these, where elements have to line up on a grid. Masonry is used all over the internet.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.